# Cron job not running after giving command in crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to run a cron job in Linux with following command:

```
crontab -e
```

typing the following details and saving it

```
MAILTO="mail@domain.com"
00 01 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I am saving this cron job. But it's not running; I'm not getting any output in mail. I don't know how to get details of the cron job which ran. Or is there a better way to run the cron job?

Answer (score 8):

The cron job you pasted will run at 1am daily, and the `> /dev/null 2>&1` part ensures that its output is thrown away.

Remove this bit if you intend to receive the script's output by e-mail.

There is a chance that your job is running, but simply failing early (perhaps because the environment provided by cron lacks things provided by your testing environment); we will know once you get the cron e-mail after re-running this job.

Comment: i updated the cron script and gave the time 5 minutes ahead.do i need to add anything else where as well in some folder?

Comment: does it depend on time on which server runs?as i am giving my location time.

Comment: Yes, it should be server time. Run `date` to know what that is.

Comment: its showing UTC time.I made the time according to that time.but no luck

Comment: I would try running the script every minute with `* * * * *`, perhaps also redirecting its output to a file (`>>/tmp/cron.log 2>&1` instead of what you had).

Comment: if date currently is 18:08.then i should give the time computing from this time? and than i can add ur content in end of script.is that al fyn?

Comment: Yes, although I would recommend removing the hour specification entirely to get rid of this unknown; if you wantto run at the 25th minute of every hour, the specification would be `25 * * * *`.

Comment: i want to run it once a day only.so i need hour paramter for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22033/discussion-between-dhag-and-micheal).